# Handshake inactivity timeout coneccting to Amazon RDS Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

I receive an error `handshake inactivity timeout` when trying to connect to a newly created Amazon RDS MySql database instance.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the security group that you have initialized with your RDS instance is correct.

By default, a default security group is selected when creating a new RDS instance. If your RDS instance is behind a firewall or other connection-limiting restriction such as behind a VPN then you won't be able to reach the RDS instance without the right security group.

The solution here is to assign the security group that allows incoming connections from your source IP address on the port designated when you created the RDS instance. The default port for MySql on RDS and MySql in general is 3306.